# How to validate with 0 if values not available in column?

Tags: postgresql

I am newbie in postgresql, Currently I am working on one project, my query works fine when values are available in column, but if values are not there I want to use 0 instead of it. How can we write validation in my query, can any one help me to solve this ?

```
select (to_char((myfirsthour) - ((mysecondhours) - ((mybreak+ myteabreak))),'FM99,999,999'))::character varying as mydaiywork
```

so here if I do not get values any one of column I want to use 0.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe can you post it as full answer if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce` (and forget the unnecessary cast to `character varying`):

```
SELECT coalesce(
          to_char(
             myfirsthour - mysecondhours + (mybreak + myteabreak),
             'FM99,999,999'
          ),
          '0'
       ) AS mydaiywork
```